# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.junit.internal.runners.ErrorReportingRunner

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, junit4, java-17

If I am using Java 8 to run a test, it is getting executed successfully but using java 17 gives the following error. The only change which I have done is changing the java version.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.junit.internal.runners.ErrorReportingRunner
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:76)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:36)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:50)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.